# Kaba 9700 not booting

Tags: networking, boot, terminal, android

I have a [Kaba terminal 9700](http://www.kaba.com/workforce-management/en/solutions/kaba-b-inspired/426188/kaba-terminal-97-00.html) and it is stuck in the boot screen:

[image: Photo: terminal stuck in the boot screen]

It's powered via PoE and is connected to the network via the PoE adapter. It should get an IP address via DHCP.

I have tried:

- turning it off and on again
- booting into service mode, but the touch buttons do not react

[image: Photo: service mode]

What can I do to make the terminal boot again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps helped:

- replace the CMOS battery
- boot into Service Mode
- choose "Mini Linux" from the selection (touch screen worked now)
- when the screen says "waiting for SSH connection", re-power to boot normally